# ¿Como envió parámetros por en el body por POST con la libreria Volley?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley

Necesito enviar unos parametros en el body por POST pero no se como se implementa o como se realiza. 
actualmente los estoy enviando con el metodo getHeaders(),
pero necesito enviarlo por el body.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega el código como texto no como imagen, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que lo que enviaras es un JSON:

```
RequestQueue rq  = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
                JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonEnviar,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject Obj = response;


                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                     }
                });
                rq.add(postRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fijate de probar algo asi:

```
    public class MyRequest extends Request<String> {


    private Map<String, String> params;

    public MyRequest(String param1, String param2, Listener<String> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.POST, "http://test.url", errorListener);
        mListener = listener;
        mParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mParams.put("paramOne", param1);
        mParams.put("paramTwo", param2);

    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return mParams;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte

Answer (score 0):

Hola Partiendo desde que estas utilizando JSON como dato ,puedes utilizar el siguiente código utilizando siempre la librería Volley.
En este caso si deseas enviar algo por el body puedes utilizar HashMap que se utiliza con un Key y Valor.
espero te sirva.

```
    /*Creamos un Objeto de tipo HashMap
    Agregamos los parametros que deseemos enviar con Key y Valor.
    */
    HashMap<String,String> hashMapToken = new HashMap<>();
    hashMapToken.put("nombre","pepito");
    /*Aqui ya hemos agredado nombre=pepito
    */
    /*
    La peticion la realizamos con JsonObjectRequest que espera envia un Json y responde lo mismo.
    parametros:TIPO PETICION(POST,GET,ect),URL,JSON y su Propio Listener para escuchar eventos de respuesta y/o Error. 
    */
    /*El Json que estariamos enviando seria 
    {"nombre":"pepito"}
    */
    JsonObjectRequest solicitud = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,"http://www.ejemplo.com",new JSONObject(hashMapToken), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject datos) {

            /*Trabajar aqui con la respuesta seria un Objeto tipo JSON*/

        }
    },new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        System.out.println("Error Response"+error.getMensage());
        }
    });

    VolleyRP.addToQueue(solicitud,mRequest,this,volley);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: Marca la respuesta que te ayudo como la correcta,Saludos.